# How to insert a BLOB_FILE into DB Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can i make an BLOB_FILE insert in PL/SQL?

My try:

```
 insert into MY TABLE (SOMETHING,SOMETHING,BLOB_FILE,SOMETHING,SOMETHING,SOMETHING) 
    values(1,'1234HRT',utl_raw.cast_to_raw('path\of\my\file'),7894,SYSDATE,SYSDATE);
```

Any tips?

Comment: You can not insert a file this way; you may have a look at [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-309085A3-9D23-4ED8-9920-E243C6406286.htm#SUTIL999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many other examples of that on other posts. You need some pl/sql to send the file to the blob column:
ps: you need to create a directory object to point to the folder

```
DECLARE
  src_lob  BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', '/tmp/me.gif');
  dest_lob BLOB;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES(2, EMPTY_BLOB())
     RETURNING doc INTO dest_lob;

  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_lob, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_lob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_lob,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_lob) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_lob);

  COMMIT;
END;
```