Insert a file as binary data to AWS S3 bucket using Athena
We are exploring the possibilities to connect AWS s3 buckets using DBEaver using Athena. Querying a single object available in the bucket is possible. We are looking for an option to to insert a binary encoded csv file to the S3 bucket.
Querying the existing S3 bucket with Athena driver

What is a "binary encoded csv file"? Can you point us to some example documentation?

My intention is to create an Insert statement in DBEaver which would insert a file to connected S3 bucket.
I am referring to an example blob file upload functionality from the below thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724926/how-to-insert-a-blob-file-into-db-oracle

Inserting data into an Athena table will create a file in S3. You should include an appropriate LOCATION when creating the table. What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific problem?
